# How to set up OAuth for managing Dialogflow user entities

Tags: google-api-php-client, dialogflow-es

I have a Dialogflow fulfillment written in PHP. It was using v1 of the Dialogflow API and I'm migrating to v2.

I don't need users to authenticate when using the app, but I used User Entities in v1 and under v2 these require authentication using OAuth.

I'm working through the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app) and having trouble with *Step 1: Configure the client object*.

Since I am halfway through executing PHP code in order to fulfill a request from the user, how should I set $client->setRedirectUri?  I need to get authorisation for the next line of code to then make a call via the Dialogflow projects.agent.sessions.entityTypes.patch API call so not sure where I would be 'redirecting' when the authorisation response comes back.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using Dialogflow library on NodeJs, here is what I did to solve the problem:

- Go to 'Settings' of the chatbot in Dialogflow.
- On General page, click on the link of Service Account (it redirects you to the Cloud Service Accounts).
- Add a new credential, with a name (you can type what you want). In permissions, search Dialogflow API Client and mark the option of JSON credential.

  - Accept and a JSON file will be downloaded.
  - Add the route of that file to your server in a .env variable with the name GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

And thats all!

Comment: Great thanks. I've built my application in PHP on a shared hosting server. I've been advised by the host that I cannot set environment variables. Are you aware of another way I could achieve this?

Comment: I know this will sound weird, but I think you can use the v1 url (https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query) to make requests to a conversational agent in v2.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much :D This has solved my problem. Probably not a permanent fix as v1 will be deprecated at some point, but at least it gives me a working solution for now until I can resolve authentication for v2.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The authorization required here isn't authorization from the user to set a Session Entity - it is authorization *of your server* to make sure it is allowed to access the API at all. You will typically do this with a [service account](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup) and keep the auth info tightly controlled. This is similar to the "API keys" that were used with V1, but is using a more standard auth method.